# Doubt over sentence formation

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> The new generation will grow up believing that the kind of language they see on tv and social media is how argument should be framed.

Now my question can "is how argument should be framed" be written as "The new generation will grow up believing that the kind of language they see on tv and social media that is how arguments should be framed."?

Comment: How "is how an argument should be used" is used as part of that sentence without that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use of argument in context.

- "...the kind of language they see on tv and social media is how *an* argument should be framed." - If you're talking about arguments generally, for example, as part of a non-specific debate, it's "an argument".
- "...the kind of language they see on tv and social media is how *the* argument should be framed." - For a specific argument regarding a particular topic - "the argument", eg "the argument against 5 substitutions in a football game."

Answer (score 0):

No, i do not think the sentence can be rephrased that way.

If you must include the 2nd 'that', then one possibility is

"The new generation will grow up believing that the kind of language they see on tv and social media 'is right, and' that is how argument should be framed."

This version is slightly verbose.